# SQL query not working in latest version of MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I want to get a specific row with the following query:

```
$wanted_term = $wpdb->get_row("
      SELECT allterms.* FROM (
      SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rownum, terms.* FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT t.*, tt.taxonomy, tt.term_taxonomy_id, tm.meta_key, tm.meta_value, tr.object_id
      FROM wp_terms AS t
      INNER JOIN wp_termmeta AS tm ON ( t.term_id = tm.term_id )
      INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id
      INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tr ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
      WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('release') /* replace taxonomy */
      AND tr.object_id IN ('.$post_id.') /* replace object_ids */
      AND ( tm.meta_key = 'timestamp' )
      ORDER BY tm.meta_value+0 DESC
      ) AS terms, (SELECT @rownum := 0) AS r
      ) AS allterms WHERE allterms.term_id='.$term_id.' /* replace term_id */");
```

However, since upgrading to latest version of MySQL, this is not working. The database did not change. Is there any standard which changed in the later versions of MySQL which is stopping this query from working as it should?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Considering your rep, I'd expect you to know we want error messages if you have them, or an explanation what is wrong if you don't.

Comment: @HoneyBadger No error messages are provided. It is returning with no results.  When in fact, there should be results there.

Comment: If you change the `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN` do you still have no records? It may be related with the join condition

Comment: If you use latest version then the best way is to rewrite your query completely for new server version features usage.

Comment: @Rui Costa Tried that, made no difference unfortunately.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson you also need to move the `WHERE` clause of the `LEFT JOIN` table conditions to the `ON` also. Otherwise it will override to an `INNER JOIN`

Comment: @RuiCosta Can you please post an answer with your suggestion so that I can see what you mean? Thanks.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson good point, still getting my bearings around Stackoverflow :). Added in the answer. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try setting an `LEFT JOIN` to validate if the problem is the `JOIN` condition.

```sql
 SELECT allterms.* FROM (
      SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rownum, terms.* FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT t.*, tt.taxonomy, tt.term_taxonomy_id, tm.meta_key, tm.meta_value, tr.object_id
      FROM wp_terms AS t
      LEFT JOIN wp_termmeta AS tm ON ( t.term_id = tm.term_id ) AND ( tm.meta_key = 'timestamp' )
      LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id AND tt.taxonomy IN ('release') /* replace taxonomy */
      LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tr ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id AND tr.object_id IN ('.$post_id.') /* replace object_ids */
      ORDER BY tm.meta_value+0 DESC
      ) AS terms, (SELECT @rownum := 0) AS r
      ) AS allterms WHERE allterms.term_id='.$term_id.' /* replace term_id */
```